# Retrieving table rows with matching values in a SET Field Type

Tags: mysql

I have a field in tables, with datatype "set" so that it can accept multiple values. But I got stuck at the time, when I am retrieving the results matching values to it.

An Example field

```
"menuPosition" : set('top','left','right','bottom')
```

An Example query

```
SELECT * FROM mytable where menuPosition='top'
```

This query only returns those rows with only `top` as their values, the rows having multiple values like `top,left` are not returned. How to retrieve all those records?

And since my above query only compares one values, how to write a query to match multiple values like `where menuPosition='top' && 'bottom'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You caeither use `FIND_IN_SET` like:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE FIND_IN_SET('top', menuPosition)
```

Or you can use `LIKE`:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE menuPosition LIKE '%top%'
```

I guess the first one is faster.

Comment: How to compare One and more values LIKE "top" & "bottom"

Comment: I just added the last line. Use `FIND_IN_SET('top', menuPosition) AND FIND_IN_SET('bottom', menuPosition)`